# Block Java Keylistener while executing previous command

Tags: java, keylistener

I´ve implemented a Keylistener in Java, which basically works, but if I hold a key pressed, it seems that all the KeyEvents are "stacked" and executed one after another. Generally, I want this behavior, but since the methods called on a Key Event take some computation time, I would like to "block" the Keylistener to accept Events while already executing a method called from a previous KeyEvent.
I already tried to set a bool flag inside the KeyListener, but it didn´t work because it seems that the Keylisteners methods are called after a previous KeyEvent is executed completely.
Any ideas how to achieve this? Thanks!

edit: Here is a code snippet how I tried it without success:

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    frame.removeMouseListener(this);
    switch (e.getKeyCode())
    {
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
    case KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN:  frame.myMethod(); break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_MINUS:
    case KeyEvent.VK_SUBTRACT: frame.myOtherMethod(); break;
    }
    frame.addMouseListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Could you not just set a flag outside of the key listener rather than inside..?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas how to achieve this?

In your KeyListener:

1. remove the KeyListener from the component
2. do the processing
3. add the KeyListener back to the component

Comment: @user3581199, then you implemented the suggestion incorrectly, or your `computations` finish faster than you think and you don't need to worry about this, or you are starting a Thread to do your computations so the GUI is free to accept new events. Too many unknowns to provide additional help. Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I added a code snippet to my initial post. Both methods, myMethod() and myOtherMethod() do not use threads. Basically, they do an image processing with Graphics2D.

Comment: @user3581199, why would you remove a MouseListener if you are trying to suppress KeyEvents?

Comment: Oh, that´s just due to copy and paste, in my actual code, I did remove/add the KeyListener.

Comment: `Oh, that´s just due to copy and paste, in my actual code,` Well, post your actual `SSCCE`. You were asked for one two days ago.